How to append textures and brushes in 4.3
How to append textures to 4.3 file from, for example, 4.1 file? I append them, they are visible in outliner and I can drag them to a viewport, but can't select them with brushes.
Here's the link with video showing problem https://youtu.be/9RJvCsEqCKQ

I guess you'll have to save them as Assets ad they'll then be available just like any other Asset. See the Blender Manual here.
